# Using cout to an object,why do we need to call by reference

Tags: c++

In the example below, i would like to know why do we use the call by reference to ostream. i got an error when i deleted the & but didnt quite get the error message.

```
 class MyArray{
    private:
        int x[10];
    public:
    MyArray(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            x[i] = n;


    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& pa, MyArray ob);
    };
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& pa, MyArray ob)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            pa << ob.x[i];
        return pa;



    }
    int main()
    {

        MyArray a(5);
        cout << a;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: because `std::ostream` has no accessible  copy or move constructors

Comment: Because if we pass it by value, we need to copy the cout object, which doesn't make sense

Comment: A little more explanation would have been perfect, i think i got it tho.
Thanks both @Malice WhizTiM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::ostream` has no "accessible" move or copy constructor. From C++11, the copy constructor is `deleted`, even the move constructor is `protected`.

When you return by value, (a move/copy constructor is necessary even if Copy elision takes place):

```
ostream operator<<(ostream& pa, MyArray ob){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        pa << ob.x[i];
    return pa;    //Move or Copy Constructor is required.
}
```

.............

[`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) is supposed to be the base class for objects that performs high level stream Output operations. It's meant to be the base class of an object that controls a [stream buffer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf).

It doesn't make sense to copy `std::cout` since, its a resource and its specified to control a stream buffer responsible for sending characters to your program's standard output.